# Save a PDF file of Sharepoint in a directory in java

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, sharepoint

I am working in a jsp file. I have a lot of files available in my Sharepoint intranet with link like this :

> http://myIntranet.eu/my%pdf%1.pdf

I want saved the pdf in a folder in my server. This will help me then to merge all PDF.
I had already merge pdf in java, but I don't know how I can save this PDF on my server. 
Can you please help me on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no web service or rest service from sharepoint to get the pdf, you can try to use an http client http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ to make request to sharpoint on java server to get the pdf file. Maybe you need authentication.

Comment: It's look like more complicatated than I had imagine!